# $scope variable is undefined in post

Tags: angularjs

I have AngularJS repeat biaya in data_biaya that I have from JSON.

When I ng-click="simpan_biaya(data_biaya)", why is the data posting undefined?

```
<input type="button" ng-click="simpan_biaya(data_biaya)" value="Simpan"/>
<tr ng-repeat="biaya in data_biaya | filter:{tahapan_id : 10}" >
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td><span >{{biaya.tanggal_transaksi}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{biaya.uraian}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{biaya.pihak_nama}}</span></td>
      <td><span >{{data_biaya[$index].pemasukan}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{biaya.pengeluaran}}</span></td>
      <td>{{biaya.sisa}}</td>
      <td><span >{{biaya.keterangan}}</span></td>
    </tr>
```

#### JavaScript

```
    var datanya=[
        {"id":"23713","id_pembiayaan":"1","perkara_id":"7200","tahapan_id":"10","kategori_id":"1","jenis_biaya_id":"1","pihak_id":null,"pihak_ke":null,"urutan":"1","jenis_transaksi":"1","tanggal_transaksi":"2016-05-26","uraian":"Panjar Biaya Perkara","pemasukan":1000000,"pengeluaran":0,"jumlah":1000000,"sisa":1000000,"keterangan":null,"pihak_nama":"Penggugat"},
        {"id":"23714","id_pembiayaan":"1","perkara_id":"7200","tahapan_id":"10","kategori_id":"11","jenis_biaya_id":"61","pihak_id":null,"pihak_ke":null,"urutan":"2","jenis_transaksi":"-1","tanggal_transaksi":"2016-05-26","uraian":"Biaya Pendaftaran\/PNBP","pemasukan":0,"pengeluaran":"30000.00","jumlah":"30000.00","sisa":970000,"keterangan":null,"pihak_nama":"Penggugat"}
  ];
    var app = angular.module('jurnalApp', []);
    app.controller('jurnalCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
      $scope.data_biaya = [];
      $scope.searchClick = function (data) {
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                      $scope.data_biaya=datanya;
                    });
            };
      $scope.simpan_biaya = function(data){
                var post_data = data;
                $.post("<?php echo base_url().'all_jurnal/set_jurnal_biaya';?>", post_data)
                    .done(function(json){

                });
            }
      angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                $scope.searchClick();
            });

    });
```

Here: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QMOJJdr0yiWJlNv3TjXa?p=preview)

[image]

Comment: plunker link is not working

Comment: actually your code works

Comment: i tried and still posting undefined

Comment: check the demo i posted it prints the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use that:

```
 var post_data = data; var dataJson=angular.toJson(post_data); $.post("
         <?php echo base_url().'all_jurnal/set_jurnal_biaya';?>", dataJson ) .done(function(json){ });
```

Comment: Im trying to bring whole data _biaya in post

Comment: ha.. it undefined because of $scope.data_biaya = []; and searchClick is not click yet ?

Comment: what about this?

`angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            $scope.searchClick();
        });`

Comment: $scope.simpan_biaya = function(data){
      var post_data = data;
       var dataJson=angular.toJson(post_data);
        var objectToSerialize={'object':dataJson};
         $http({
            url: "/",
            method: "POST",
            data: $.param(objectToSerialize),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            }
          })

      // $scope.searchClick();
     }

Comment: {'object':dataJson} object is you param will use in your server.

Comment: or like that will work and what you want: 

`var post_data = data;
       var dataJson=angular.toJson(post_data);
      $.post("<?php echo base_url().'all_jurnal/set_jurnal_biaya';?>", dataJson
)
                    .done(function(json){

                });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <input type="button" ng-click="simpan_biaya(data_biaya)" value="Simpan"/>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fFnBw3YVVmzpurwGBsos?p=info)**

Based on the attached screenshot, you should pass JSON data, convert the data to JSON before passing:

```
 var dataJson=angular.toJson(post_data);
```

Comment: yes it is what i want, could you explain why i cant see it from firebug?

Comment: you mean when passing the data ?

Comment: you might need to debug and check what is passing in the network.

Comment: why did you remove the answer?